# How to combine multiple Apps (Apk) into one single App

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to combine multiple apps (Apk) into one single App.

And also have all the features of the other apps running in the single App?

Comment: You could launch intents to other apps using their package name, then it would be seen as "one app", in a way

Comment: For instance, if you have 3 apps that you want to combine into 1 app. 

Using your approach, will the other remaining apps have their icons hidden on the users desktop?

Comment: Only if their manifests are not defining a launcher activity will they be hidden. There is no way to "merge and hide" apps after they are installed